# host not found in upstream in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf when running standalone docker containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, nginx, amazon-ecs

I have 2 containers named - flask_server and nginx , when I run those containers with docker-compose everything works as expected , the problem is that when I run each container separately I get this error massage :

```
"host not found in upstream "flask_server:3000" in /etc/nginx/conf.d/nginx.conf".
```

I have searched for a solution and I came into the conclusion that this is networking issue between the containers .

so when I run the containers with the --network flag like so :

```
**flask_server**
docker run -p 3000:3000 --network custom-network flask_server
**nginx**
docker run -p 80:80 --network custom-network nginx
```

its still not working .

The only way I made it work is by running the flask_server container with the --network-alias flag like so:

```
**flask_server**
docker run -p 3000:3000 --network custom-network --network-alias flask_server flask_server
**nginx**
docker run -p 80:80 --network custom-network nginx
```

So now I'm getting into another problem which is that I want to upload these containers into amazon ecs and I don't see any alias option in the task definition, So I'll probably need to think of another creative way to resolve this issue before I upload these containers into ecs.

**nginx.conf**

```
upstream flask_server {
server flask_server:3000;
}

server {

listen 80;
server_name default_server;

location /api {
    proxy_pass http://flask_server;

    
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }

}
```

**nginx Dockerfile**

```
FROM nginx

RUN rm /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d
```

**flask Dockerfile**

```
FROM python

WORKDIR /app

COPY ./requirements.txt /app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install python3-dev  -y

WORKDIR /app/code

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["gunicorn", "wsgi:app", "-k gevent" ,"-w 3", "-b 0.0.0.0:3000", "-t 30"]
```

hope anyone here has another workaround to solve this networking problem between the containers, or a way to use the --network-alias flag on Amazon ECS.

Any help would be great. Thanks !

**============ EDIT ==============**

So I found A workaround to this problem and instead of using the flask_server as my internal ip and proxy pass to the container itself , I used the host ip and passes the requests to the host ip directly .

be aware that this will only work if the flask_server container is running before the nginx In order for the requests to be forwarded to the nginx .

**New nginx.conf file**

```
server {

    listen 80;
    server_name default_server;

    location /api {
        # the host variable indicates the current host ip address
        proxy_pass http://$host:3000;

        
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I you want to connect to a docker instance in your local network, you need to pass `--network="host"`.

For ECS, you can not connect with named alias. You need to either connect via public IP or setup a VPC and connect via internal IP.